# How to cache a datagridview in windows forms application

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio-2012, datagridview

I am working on an application in which data is retrieved from four `SQL` tables using `joins` and the retrieved data is populated to a `datagridview` on a windows form.
I have two `Radio Buttons` `ALL` and `DrawDate` , by default `ALL` Radio Button is selected and once the application is opened it populates all the data on to the `datagridview` and when I select `DrawDate Radio Button`, only the data related to that draw date is populated on the `datagridview`. Everything looks fine until then but after selecting `DrawDate Radio Button` and if a user want to get all the data again by selecting `ALL` `Radio Button`, it again loads all data from the database server which is not preferred. 
Is there any better way I can cache the data populated once the application is opened and populate it when a user selects `ALL` `Radio Button` later when he needs it?

**C# Code**

```
sqlcon = GetConnectionString();
            try
            {
                sqlcon.Open();

                //var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

                for (int i = 0; i < dgvPaymentsReceived_Collections.RowCount; i++)
                {
                    int trademonth = Convert.ToInt32(dgvPaymentsReceived_Collections.Rows[i].HeaderCell.Value);


                    for (int j = 0; j < dgvPaymentsReceived_Collections.ColumnCount; j++)
                    {
                        int paymentmonth = Convert.ToInt32(dgvPaymentsReceived_Collections.Columns[j].HeaderCell.Value);

                        //var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

                        SqlCommand cmd_PaymentsReceived = new SqlCommand();

                        cmd_PaymentsReceived.Connection = sqlcon;
                        cmd_PaymentsReceived.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        cmd_PaymentsReceived.CommandText = sp_PaymentsReceved_Collections;

                        cmd_PaymentsReceived.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@trademonth", trademonth));
                        cmd_PaymentsReceived.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@paymentmonth", paymentmonth));


                        SqlDataAdapter da_PaymentsReceived_Collections = new SqlDataAdapter();
                        DataTable dt_PaymentsReceived_Colletions = new DataTable();

                        da_PaymentsReceived_Collections.SelectCommand = cmd_PaymentsReceived;
                        da_PaymentsReceived_Collections.Fill(dt_PaymentsReceived_Colletions);

                        //sw.Stop();
                        //MessageBox.Show(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds.ToString());

                        dgvPaymentsReceived_Collections.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value = dt_PaymentsReceived_Colletions.Rows[0][0].ToString();

                    }
                }

                sqlcon.Close();
            }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown us any code. What kind of connection did you use? Don't bind your database source to a datagridview - use either an `Enumerable`/`IList` collection or `DataSet` as your data holder and then assign only the part of it (filtering it with LINQ) to your datagridview. This way you don't have to create a new collection every time in memory, just iterate over the items with given condition.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have tons and tons of data, you could store the SQL results in a DataTable and then bind that to the DataGridView

Comment: Note you can also use the caching object from asp.net to do caching: System.Web.Caching.  But unless you need all the features it is probably overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider storing the SQL data in a `IEnumerable` data structure when `All` button is clicked, and bind that collection to the gridview, and during the `DrawDate` button click, sort the collection appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

You can hang on to your original data table and create a separate DataTable to bind to your DataGridView if you want to be able to change what is displayed.

Just fill your data table once, and then create a new DataTable to hide what you don't need.

This might use slightly more memory depending on the size of your DataTable, but it's probably the easiest solution to implement.

```
    DataTable viewedData = dt_PaymentsReceived_Colletions;

    if(hideIncome.Checked) {
        viewedData.Columns.Remove("Income");
        viewedData.AcceptChanges();
    }

    DataGridView1.DataSource = viewedData;
```